# Save data randomly generated into label

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am fairly new to coding and was wondering if it was possible to save data I have randomly generated into a label. I can randomly generate the data and input it into the label but I am having difficulties saving the previous data from the label to an array. Is it possible to do this? And how would it be done?

Essentially I want the user to be able to go back to the previous text in the label if they press a button

Thank you for any help.

code:

This is how I am generating the random variable from an array which contains quotes

```
//right hand button tapped

@IBAction func RHSButton(_ sender: Any) {

// randomises variable to display
    var randomQuote: String {
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myQuotes.count)))
        return myQuotes[randomNumber]}

   quotesLabel.text = randomQuote

}
```

I want to be able to store the data into an array called:

```
var randomGeneratedQuotes : [String] = []
```

But I am not quite sure how

Comment: I have updated the questions now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you could save the value of your label into your `randomGeneratedQuotes` array just before you generate a new random value.

```
var randomQuote: String {
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myQuotes.count)))
    return myQuotes[randomNumber]
}

@IBAction func RHSButton(_ sender: Any) {
   //If a value is present, save it
   if let oldValue = quotesLabel.text {
       randomGeneratedQuotes.append(oldValue)
   }

   //and update the value
   quotesLabel.text = randomQuote
}
```

From your previous questions I'm guessing you'd like a `LHSButton` function to give you the previous value, that could look like so:

```
@IBAction func LHSButton(_ sender: Any) {
   //Do we have a previous value?
   if randomGeneratedQuotes.count > 0 {
       //take that
       let previousValue = randomGeneratedQuotes.removeLast()
       //and use it
       quotesLabel.text = previousValue
   }       
}
```

Hope that works and helps.

Comment: thank you so much. I have been so frustrated. this works great

Comment: Glad you got it working and don't worry, you'll soon find a new programming problem to be frustrated about, it never ends :)

Answer (score 1):

hi seems like u want undo feature.

take one more array and add selected randomNumber

on clicking button display last index of array and remove it from array.